# Java Request Codes in constant variables

Tags: java, android

According to the docs for this function: [startActivityForResult()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#startActivityForResult%28android.content.Intent%2C%20int%29)

I'm seeing that there is a request code that it accepts.  If I understand correctly I'll use this same code to refer to the results of this activity.  Is it common practice to put these resource links in constant variables?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If by "constant variables" you mean `static final int` variables, then yes. It is not necessary, but it helps make for more readable code.